# Qt How to Find Object on a widget using x() and y() position

Tags: qt

I have a MainWindow. On MainWindow I have multiple Qlabel's. Now, i need to find the QLabel clicked.
Using  MousePressEvent, i can get the X() and Y() position of the mouse clicked.

How can i use this Co-ordinate to identify the QLabel??

Is there any function in QT to find the Object clicked using X() and Y() co-ordinate??

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since QLabel is a subclass of QWidget, you can handle mouse press events in QLabel::mousePressEvent

```
virtual void mousePressEvent ( QMouseEvent * ev )
```

But in QMainWindow, you can use childAt to get the child widgets at x,y

```
QWidget * QWidget::childAt ( int x, int y ) const

QLabel* label= static_cast<QLabel*>(mainWindow->childAt(x,y));
```

Read more at:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#childAt

Comment: Thanks digitalSurgeon, i tried using your way. It gives address in return. Means in debugging mode, label shows the address "@819d4e8". Now how to use this address in identifying the label clicked. Please provide me some more guidlines.

Comment: @skg what you are getting is a pointer to the label, so you don't need to do any thing else, you can call functions on this pointer..

`QLabel* label= static_cast<QLabel*>(mainWindow->childAt(x,y));
label->setText("I am the label you clicked");
`

Answer (score 4):

In Qt5 this also works

```
QTabBar *widget =(QTabBar*) qApp->widgetAt(QCursor::pos());
```

Comment: +1 for the QCursor::pos() which seems to be working, whereas QMouseEvent::pos() does not work for me.

Comment: Only thing it's not strict matching what I mean is you may get any QWidget pointer use qbject_cast for better results

Answer (score 2):

Rather than trying to identify which label has been clicked on from mouse coordinates, you could also alternatively use a label's [`mousePressEvent()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlabel.html#mousePressEvent) method.

For example, make your own overloaded label class and, on a `mousePressEvent()` emit a `clicked()` signal which you can then bind to a slot.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `widgetAt` function inside `QApplication`

```
QWidget *widget = qApp->widgetAt(x,y);
```

which then you can `dynamic_cast` into `QLabel`.

Comment: Thanks Ismail, can you please provide me little more idea ??
I tried this, it gives "0x0" everytime for any label.