# How to move a set of buttons in Qt?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt4, qt4.8

Currently I have a set of buttons in a QVBoxLayout which is inside a QHBoxLayout.

Is there a way to move these according to where my mouse is?

My current code is like this:

```
    self.button1 = QPushButton()
    self.button1.setText("button A")

    self.button2 = QPushButton()
    self.button2.setText("button B")

    vbox = QVBoxLayout(self.canvas)
    vbox.addStretch(1)
    vbox.addWidget(self.button1)
    vbox.addWidget(self.button2)

    hbox = QHBoxLayout(self.window)
    hbox.addStretch(1)
    hbox.addLayout(vbox)"
```

Comment: Of course there is a way: with calling addWidget/removeWidget. Just keep the reference pointer to the object you are moving. Handling events and detecting what's there under the mouse cursor is a bit of a challenge.

Comment: @AlexanderVX can you maybe complete the above code? The addWidget method does not specify the location, so assuming I have point x, y. How should I move the two buttons to the location?

Comment: Ah, yes, insertWidget is more convenient for that.

Answer (score 0):

The prototype for moving some button widget would be:

```
vbox.removeWidget(self.button) // that only needs the reference to your button item
vbox.insertWidget(newPos, self.button) // mind the difference in target position when you remove one item
```

That does not cover event processing. With two buttons you can either do that twice for each or maybe altogether, mind the target positions.

Or you can move an entire layout within another layout for the group of buttons in a very similar fashion. That'd be moving layout item. As long as you don't imply those buttons cannot be moved separately the example is for individual buttons. Oh, there is some Qt C++ [discussion](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/7264-Moving-widgets-within-a-layout) about that.

Comment: excuse me if I am wrong, but from the online documentation, the only insertWidget method is like this: insertWidget( int index, QWidget * widget, int stretch = 0, Qt::Alignment alignment = 0 ). And none of the parameter takes a QPoint/QPointF as parameter.

Comment: Duly noted, parameters are corrected. As for QPoint I assume you may find the other part of answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12350658/qt-how-to-find-object-on-a-widget-using-x-and-y-position Your question is not the easy one to be able to cover everything in few lines. It is possible to implement what you want but for more details you can ask more specific questions.